# Create new custom project template categories not working as expected in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project-template

I followed the steps as mentioned in this article of msdn:
[create new custom project template categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx)

But it doesn't create my custom category but shows the custom project template under root category i.e. Visual C#.

Any one who might have successfully created a sub-category under "Visual C#" in New Project dialog?

I want something like this, where **"My Own Templates"** should be on left pane and should show all the custom templates under it on right pane:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this before but didn't get it working. But now it works like a charm. Here is the link that really is straight forward and easy to follow:
[VS Custom Templates](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/08/20/Visual-Studio-custom-templates.aspx?Page=1)

I missed this [I guess] `Uncheck the option to "Automatically import the template into Visual Studio" for better control of how the template will appear in the Visual Studio.` as mentioned in the second page of the article.